# xampp tomcat won't start, tried several solutions didn't work well

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, xampp

i've tried several solutions both i found on stackoverflow/other forums/articles but none of them working..

Below are solutions i've tried with xampp-tomcat "return code 1" problem:

```
 - Run as Administrator (still "return code 1")
 - Reinstall Xampp (no change either "return code 1")
 - Add more Variables into System Variables (CLASSPATH, CATALINA_HOME, and other things that i've forgotten.. it is that much indeed)
 - Lookup for port 8080, 8005, 8009 with telnet command but none of these show up on the list either
 - Check with port checker online it shows up "Port xxxx is closed" (8080, 8005, 8009)
 - Reinstall Java JDK
 - Check if java jdk really installed by using "java -version" and "javac" to see if the following command executed properly (and yes, it is working)
 - Read xampp/tomcat/logs catalina.pid (i don't understand the point of reading PID Numbers? aren't that log supposed to be "more information"? maybe that's not the PID i've thinking of.. because that, i've tried to search it on google and google says no)
```

Still, none of these working for me.. i also tried to search other XAMPP Alternative for running JSP/Tomcat but unfortunately i can't find one either. If someone knows other XAMPP Alternative for running JSP/Tomcat please tell me that instead because all of these XAMPP Solutions are really getting to my nerves.

Comment: Maybe Server Fault (another stackoverflow comunity) could be best to ask this type of question

Comment: You can use tomcat separately to run JSP.